# Local extrema of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus

I have a continuous function which is defined on a compact set. I need to find the local minimum and maximum. I follow these steps:

1. Find the critical points(partial derivatives must be equal to zero)
2. Use the second derivative test to determine if it is a minimum or maximum or a saddle point

My questions are:

1. Can the critical point be on the boundary of the compact set? And what to do if all points where the partial derivatives are 0 are on the boundaries of the set?
2. Can I find local extremas over a bounded set? I think the set where the function is defined should be an open set.

Idea that I came up with: If the set is compact, I search for local extremas only in the interior of the set, without the boundaries?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The second question is simple
Let $A=\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\times [0,1]$ and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=sin(x)+\frac{y^{2}}{2}$. So $\nabla f(x,y)=(cos(x),y)$. The global (so, local) maximum of $f$ is at $a=\left(\frac{\pi}{2},1\right)$ and the global (so, local) minimun of $f$ is at $b=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right)$. See that $a,b\in\partial A$. So not necessarilly the local extremas belongs to the interior.

The first question has a discussion. I see two different definitions of critical point. One says that a critical point is a point satisfying that the derivative is zero or is not defined at this point. Other says that a critical point is a point that the  derivative is zero.

With the first definition, my example above show two critical points at the boundary. But with the first definition the question makes no sense.